# CSS last-child not overriding parent border

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, overriding

First of all let me start by saying I'm fairly new to CSS, mostly done styling inline. What I'm doing is using an `<ul>` as a menu, where the `<li>` items are menu items. Right borders are used as dividers between the menu items, but visually it would be better if the last menu item doesn't have the right border.

CSS code

```
.gf-menu.l1 > li > .item:after
{
    border-right: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.gf-menu.l1 > li:first-child
{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.gf-menu.l1 > li:last-child 
{
    margin-right: 5px;
    border-right: 0;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="gf-menu l1 ">
    <li class="item487">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_1
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item488">
        <a class="item" href="link2">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item489">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can only assume it has something to do with the `after` element as the margin is actually being added in the right place, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just did one fiddle .... but I'm not so sure if every code is there, could you check that please
http://jsfiddle.net/e2w6r8et/

Comment: What what what code is this? Where is the border in the fiddle?

Comment: yes where is the border but if you want to remove last child border then use this ul li:last-child { border-right:none;} or read here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: for more info, i just gave structure but if you will share working code then will give you final answer. thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used your **HTML** and wrote minimal **CSS** for you to understand

**TIP :** Give classes and id's name which have semantic meaning to it. It is difficult to code when you give class names like these.

```css
.gf-menu.l1 li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
}

.gf-menu.l1 li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gf-menu l1 ">
    <li class="item487">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_1
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item488">
        <a class="item" href="link2">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item489">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed `display: inline-block;` and got the exact same behaviour as before, but without the last right border. Note: the class names are generated by joomla, that's why there so meaningless. Thanks again for helping.

Comment: Ah I see! Welcome anyway :)

Comment: Quick update for anyone that stumbles on this: The inline behaviour was defined in `.gf-menu` already. It's the padding I changed, sorry about that.

Comment: As a good practice, you should apply the `padding` on the `a` element instead of the `li`.

Comment: Ok, and does `.gf-menu.l1 > li > .item` refer to the `a` element in this case? Is that the same as `.gf-menu.l1 > li a.item` in your example? Not really familiar with the format yet.

Comment: @OhboydoItry `a.item` is to select only the `a` **with** the class `.item` (while `a .item` would select the `.item` objects with `a` as parent). In your  case `.gf-menu.l1 > li > .item` **or** `.gf-menu.l1 > li > a` works. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any `:after`.

Here is a solution with a few **advices**:

https://jsfiddle.net/c4Lrmpfx/

```css
.gf-menu.l1 {
   list-style: none;
}
.gf-menu.l1 > li {
   float: left;
   text-align: center;
}
.gf-menu.l1 > li a.item {
   /* Better to apply the style to the A instead of the LI,
       also to style the clickable area */
   display: block;
   padding: 10px;
   text-decoration: none;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);   
}
.gf-menu.l1 > li a.item:hover {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.gf-menu.l1 > li:not(:last-child) a.item{
   border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="gf-menu l1 ">
    <li class="item487">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_1
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item488">
        <a class="item" href="link2">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
    <li class="item489">
        <a class="item" href="link1">
            menu_item_2
        </a>      
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here I used the selector `:not` instead of having an other line to define the `last-child` as `border-right: 0;`

Here `:not` specifies that the `:last-child` won't be included for the following properties.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, the border was fixed by Sidsec9's reply but I'll look at this for the hover behaviour!

Comment: Yep, his solution is completely correct. Just have a look in my answer about the `:not` and in the comment in code about **the style on the A element**. This is a good practice, you should keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: That's really clever haha, I'm taking notes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not far off... If you're trying to get them to display next to each other then you need to change your CSS to:

```
gf-menu.l1 li {
display: inline;
border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: atleast read the question first before giving the answer.This is not op asked.

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted that in your question then. When people copy your code and run it, the fact that's missing puts them in a regular UL. @Leothelion not sure what you're referring to but given the code, this does exactly what the OP asked for, while you're asking people to read before posting, perhaps you could run a spellcheck.

Comment: @DylanB, don't take me comment in other way but still i think  you did not read the question. So telling you. OP don't want right border in last li of ul so please tell me where you write the code to remove the last li's right border? now you got me?